# will have an operation / going to have an operation / has an operation

Tags: future-time

Which version is idiomatic? If more than one version is idiomatic, explain the difference please. I've tried to explain why each sentence can/can't be used. I need a native speaker's view on that.

> He is in hospital. He **will have an operation** tomorrow. *<--- Can't Future Simple be used here because the man has the arrangement with hospital about that operation?*
>
> He is in hospital. He's **going to have an operation** tomorrow. *([NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will%20have%20an%20operation%2Cgoing%20to%20have%20an%20operation&year_start=1880&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3#)) <--- Present Continuous because of the arrangement with hospital*
>
> He is in hospital. He **has an operation** tomorrow. *<--- Present Simple because of timetable on that operation*

Comment: "He has an operation tomorrow" sounds like you're talking about an appointment I feel, but "he's going to have an operation tomorrow" sounds like you have a more personal connection I guess? The last version you listed feels sort of detached, I guess. That's my take

Comment: By idiomatic, I assume you mean "sounds natural" and not if there is an idiom here.

Comment: All three sound fine to me, although the sentences could be joined more smoothly. I suspect that some people might not like the third example because the present tense is used differently in each sentence; in the first, it is describing a present event, but in the second, it is describing a future event. That doesn't really bother me, though.

Comment: All are possible; I find the second the most idiomatic. "He has an operation tomorrow" would more likely be said of the surgeon than the patient.